# Why is $stateChangeStart triggering multiple times?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use `$stateChangeStart` with ui router in a controller. It seems like everytime it's fired, the callback fires +1 times more than the last time.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    console.log('$stateChangeStart');
});
```

For example, on first change start `console.log` will be fired once. second time `console.log` will be fired twice, etc etc.

I know using `event.preventDefault()` will stop this behavior, but it'll also stop all behaviors and that's not a realistic solution to me.

I do have a solution although I feel like there might be a more intelligent way to handle this:

```
var stateChangeStarted = false;
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event){
    if(!stateChangeStarted) {
        stateChangeStarted = true;
        console.log('$stateChangeStart');
    }
});
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and what else I can do to prevent this?

Answer (score 18):

Your controller is instantiated by ui-router every time you enter the state it is associated with. Therefore, your `$rootScope.$on` call will be adding a new listener to the `$stateChangeStart` event each time you enter that state.

If you only need to handle the event once per controller instance, you can save the deregister function that `$rootScope.$on` returns and execute it from within the listener callback.

```
var deregisterStateChangeStart = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event) {
    // Do something here.

    deregisterStateChangeStart();
});
```

Comment: If you're in the same controller going from one state url to another state url, this stateChangeStart only fires once.

Answer (score 9):

Clear out the listeners for stateChangeStart at the beginning of your controller.

```
$rootScope.$$listeners.$stateChangeStart = [];
```